# python function(or a code block) runs much slower with a time interval in a loop

Tags: python, performance, caching, memory, cpython

I notice a case in python, when a block of code, nested in a loop, runs continuously, it is much faster than running with some **`.sleep()`** time interval.

I wonder **the reason** and a **possible solution**.

I guess it's related to CPU-cache or some mechanism of cPython VM.

```
'''
Created on Aug 22, 2015

@author: doge
'''

import numpy as np
import time
import gc
gc.disable()

t = np.arange(100000)

for i in xrange(100):

    #np.sum(t)
    time.sleep(1) #--> if you comment this line, the following lines will be much faster

    st = time.time()
    np.sum(t)
    print (time.time() - st)*1e6
```

**result:**

```
without sleep in loop, time consumed:   50us
with  a sleep in loop, time consumed: >150us
```

some disadvantage of the `.sleep()` is, that it releases CPU, thus I provide the exactly same version with a **`C`** code below:

```
'''
Created on Aug 22, 2015

@author: doge
'''

import numpy as np
import time
import gc
gc.disable()

t = np.arange(100000)

count = 0
for i in xrange(100):

    count += 1
    if ( count % 1000000 != 0 ):
        continue
    #--> these three lines make the following lines much slower

    st = time.time()
    np.sum(t)
    print (time.time() - st)*1e6
```

**another experiment:** *(we remove the for loop)*

```
st = time.time()
np.sum(t)
print (time.time() - st)*1e6

st = time.time()
np.sum(t)
print (time.time() - st)*1e6

st = time.time()
np.sum(t)
print (time.time() - st)*1e6

...

st = time.time()
np.sum(t)
print (time.time() - st)*1e6
```

**result:**

```
execution time decreased from 150us -> 50us gradually.
and keep stable in 50us.
```

to find out whether this is problem of CPU-cache, I wrote a **`C`** counterpart. And have found out that this kind of phenomenon does not happen.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define num 100000

using namespace std;

long gus()
{
    struct timeval tm;
    gettimeofday(&tm, NULL);
    return ( (tm.tv_sec % 86400 + 28800) % 86400 )*1000000 + tm.tv_usec;
}

double vec_sum(double *v, int n){
    double result = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i < n;++i){
         result += v[i];
    }
    return result;
}

int main(){

double a[num];

for(int i = 0; i < num; ++i){
    a[i] = (double)i;
}

//for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i){
// cout<<a[i]<<"\n";
//}

int count = 0;
long st;
while(1){
++count;

if(count%100000000 != 0){    //---> i use this line to create a delay, we can do the same way in python, result is the same
//if(count%1 != 0){
continue;
}

st = gus();
vec_sum(a,num);
cout<<gus() - st<<endl;

}


return 0;
}
```

**result:**

```
time stable in 250us, no matter in "count%100000000" or "count%1"
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation; it's unclear what you're actually doing.

Comment: @Cyphase really sorry about the indentation. my first question. I've fix the python code. Can u see again?

Comment: why is `st = time.time()` etc... inside the loop? is that an indentation error?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist right. it's nested in the loop

Comment: why i can't  @ somebody @hiroprotagonist

Comment: Why do you think `time.sleep()` and `gettimeofday()` perfom equivalent actions?

Comment: @doge, no problem :).

Comment: @mathias i use counter%10000 to create counterpart of sleep

Comment: As an aside, you can do:
`from time import sleep,time` 
this would make your code a bit more readable and pythonic IMO since you now can write:
`sleep(1); 

st = time()`

Comment: What about without a loop? Do you see a similar slow down.

Comment: @Maikflow thanks. But problem is quite difficult.

Comment: @JashandeepSohi i've tried this case. update info to this post. in short, the execution time gradually decreases to fastest execution time. like from 150us to 50us. then stable in 50us

Comment: @doge you know, the counterpart of `time.sleep(x)` is `usleep(x*10000000)` from `<unistd.h>`, not some crazy fancy random computation...

Comment: @Maikflow how does inflating a namespace make code more Pythonic and readable?

Answer (score 1):

(not an answer - but too long to post as comment)

i did some experimentation and ran (something slightly simpler) through `timeit`.

```
from timeit import timeit
import time

n_loop = 15
n_timeit = 10
sleep_sec = 0.1

t = range(100000)

def with_sleep():
    for i in range(n_loop):
        s = sum(t)
        time.sleep(sleep_sec)

def without_sleep():
    for i in range(n_loop):
        s = sum(t)

def sleep_only():
     for i in range(n_loop):
        time.sleep(sleep_sec)

wo = timeit(setup='from __main__ import without_sleep',
           stmt='without_sleep()',
           number = n_timeit)
w = timeit(setup='from __main__ import with_sleep',
            stmt='with_sleep()',
            number = n_timeit)
so = timeit(setup='from __main__ import sleep_only',
            stmt='sleep_only()',
            number = n_timeit)

print(so - n_timeit*n_loop*sleep_sec, so)
print(w - n_timeit*n_loop*sleep_sec, w)
print(wo)
```

the result is:

```
0.031275457000447204 15.031275457000447
1.0220358229998965 16.022035822999896
0.41462676399987686
```

the first line is just to check that the the sleep function uses about `n_timeit*n_loop*sleep_sec` seconds. so if this value is *small* - that should be ok.

but as you see - your findings remain: the loop with the sleep function (subtracting the time sleep uses) takes up more time than the loop without sleep...

i don't think that python optimizes the loop without sleep (a c compiler might; the variable `s` is never used).