# how to handle cpu cache in python ( or fastest way to call a function once)

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, unix, caching

I find out that python's VM seems to be very unfriendly with CPU-Cache.

for example:

```
import time
a = range(500)

sum(a)

for i in range(1000000): #just to create a time interval, seems this disturb cpu cache?
    pass


st = time.time()
sum(a)
print (time.time() - st)*1e6
```

time:

```
> 100us
```

another case:

```
import time
a = range(500)

for i in range(100000):
    st = time.time()
    sum(a)
    print (time.time() - st)*1e6
```

time:

```
~ 20us
```

we can see when running frequently, the code becomes much faster.

is there a solution?

we can refer to this question:(should be the same problem)
[python function(or a code block) runs much slower with a time interval in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32153178/python-functionor-a-code-block-runs-much-slower-with-a-time-interval-in-a-loop)

I feel this question is very difficult. one must has indepth unstanding about the mechanism of python virtual machine, c and cpu-cache.

Do you have any suggestion about where to post this question for a possible answer?

Comment: A solution to what?  What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @BrenBarn a solution to make code run faster in the first case.

Comment: You have just create a list of 1000000 integer object ! Sure it's disturb CPU cache ! It's not a problem of python VM... You need to provide a more useful exemple...

Answer (score 5):

Your hypothesis "we can see when running frequently, the code becomes much faster" is not quite correct.

This loop

```
#just to create a time interval, seems this disturb cpu cache?
for i in range(1000000): 
    pass
```

isn't merely a simple time delay. In Python 2 it creates a list of 1,000,000 integer objects, loops over it, and then destroys it. In Python 3, `range()` is a generator, so it's much less wasteful of memory; the Python 2 equivalent is `xrange()`.

In the standard CPython implementation, a list is an array of pointers to the objects it contains. On a 32 bit system, an integer object occupies 12 bytes, an empty list object occupies 32 bytes, and of course a pointer occupies 4 bytes. So `range(1000000)` consumes a total of 32 + 1000000 * (4 + 12) = 16000032 bytes.

Once the loop finishes, the reference count on the `range()` list drops to zero so it and its contents are eligible for garbage collection. It takes a little bit of time to garbage collect a million integers, so it's not surprising that you notice a time delay after the loop is finished. Also, the process of creating & deallocating all those objects will generally cause some memory fragmentation, and that will impact the efficiency of subsequent code.

FWIW, on my 2GHz Pentium 4 Linux system, your 1st code block prints values in the range 38 - 41µs, but if I change the loop to use `xrange()` then the time drops to 31 - 34µs.

If the code is modified to prevent garbage collection of the `range()` until after `sum(a)` is calculated, then it makes little difference in the timing whether we use `range()` or `xrange()`.

```
import time

a = range(500)
sum(a)

bigrange = xrange(1000000)

for i in bigrange:
    pass

st = time.time()
sum(a)
print (time.time() - st) * 1e6

#Maintain a reference to bigrange to prevent it 
#being garbage collected earlier
print sum(bigrange)
```

Comment: It is not about the list. [I see the same behavior on Python 2/3, Pypy, Jython.](https://github.com/zed/test-performance-run-in-a-loop-vs-run-standalone)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Ah, ok. But it appears to me that the list garbage collection has _some_ impact. At least, it obscures the effect that the OP is trying to measure. :)

Comment: @jfs did you try with sleep method in python to delay time instead of looping

Comment: `range()` in Python 3 does not return a list (so no list to garbage collect). Can't answer on the loop vs. sleep: forgot the subtleties involved in the benchmark--it doesn't claim more than that the behavior appears to be the same between different Python versions/implementations despite the drastic difference in `range()` impl.